# Where to write @property directive in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, compiler-directives

*code1*

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject   
{
    int width,height;
}
@property int width,height;
```

*code2*

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
@property int width,height;
{
    int width,height;
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what is different between them? And in `@property` I already put `int` for `width` and `height`. Why do we need to declare it again in curly brackets？

Update: 
I am using osx 10.8 64bit.

Comment: Is there a problem with one or the other, or are you just not sure why you need to declare it as a property, and in the brackets?

Comment: if I put {init width,height},I will get some kind error.

Comment: If you put `{int width,height;}` where you get what error?  Try being more specific.

Comment: The difference is that the second one is illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example "code1" is correct but possibly unneeded, while "code2" is incorrect and won't compile. Any instance variables need to be declared in curly brackets directly after the @interface line which is why the second example is wrong.

As some others has mentioned you may not need to declare `width` and `height` at all. If you are using the modern runtime the compiler can tell from the `@property` statement that you meant to have an underlying instance variable for the property and will create these for you. On the other hand with the older legacy runtime the instance variables like `width` and `height` must be explicitly declared. You didn't specify your platform so it is no clear if it is needed in your case.

The modern runtime is always used on iOS, which is why many people here will tell you incorrectly that the instance variables do not need to be declared in any case. On Mac OS X the modern runtime is used with 64-bit code in 10.5 or newer. If you are using 32-bit code or an older version you need to explicitly declare your instance variables.

Comment: Thanks. really helps for someone who new to objc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to redeclare, just use:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
@property int width,height;
@end
```

Comment: The asker has not specified an OS. What you said is not true in general on Mac OS X.

Comment: oh! sorry, yes that's definitely iOS only. I guess force of habit.

Comment: @torrey.lyons: Declaring ivars explicitly has not been necessary on OS X since before 10.6. Only if you're building a 32-bit application can you not synthesize ivars.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Exactly. I gave the exact requirements in my answer. For what its worth our Mac app does target 32/64 bit and so we have been required to declare ivars.

Answer (score 0):

The names inside the braces are instance variables which may or may not be used as backing storage for the matching properties.  It depends on how you write your `@synthesize` statements.

I would prefer to not have explicit instance variables at all.  The only reason I have used them in this kind of situation is to make debugging easier.

Comment: Just curious, how does declaring explicit ivars aid in debugging?  Do the symbols show up more reliably?

Comment: In Xcode 4.2 (at least) synthesized instance variables didn't show up (or not consistently) in the display window under the owning object.  gdb and lldb have also had various troubles in the console with 'po' of synthesized variables or dot notation property references.  (I've **just** moved to 4.4 and am very interested in whether there are debugger fixes...of many kinds.)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between them is that the first one is right and the second one is wrong. Even if the second code compiles, that is not how you should write your code. Always put all property declarations after the ivars (the things in the curly brackets. And the @property doesn't declare the variables (that's done in the curly brackets). The @property directive gives instructions to the compiler on how to generate the getter and setter methods when you use the @synthesize directive, which you should do in your implementation file.